# Python: returning the cell coordinates

Tags: python

I am stuck on writing a function that takes in an integer value of the size that will return all the cell coordinates.

For example: if the size is 1 then it will return (0,0). If the size is 2, then it will return (0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1)

This is what I have done so far

```
def get_cells(size):

    for x_axis in range(0, size):
        x = x_axis
        for y_axis in range(0, size):
            y = y_axis
    return (x, y)
```

This code only returns the very last cell coordinate... How would I make it to return all the cell coordinates in a dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
def get_cells(size):
    result = []
    for x_axis in range(size):
        for y_axis in range(size):
            result.append((x_axis, y_axis))
    return result
```

which could be further simplified (using a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)) to:

```
def get_cells(size):
    return [(x_axis, y_axis) for x_axis in range(size) for y_axis in range(size)]
```

which could be further simplified (using [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)) to:

```
import itertools as IT
def get_cells(size):
    return list(IT.product(range(size), repeat=size))
```

Note that it is not really necessary to define a function for this at all, since the result is just a one-liner. You could use `IT.product(range(size), repeat=size)` directly instead of defining `get_cells`.

---

```
In [1]: import itertools as IT

In [2]: list(IT.product(range(2), repeat=2))
Out[2]: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you would prefer a list instead of a dictionary to contain all the co-ordinates as tuples.

```
def get_cells(size):
    my_list = []
    for x_axis in range(0, size):
        x = x_axis
        for y_axis in range(0, size):
            y = y_axis
            my_list.append((x, y))
    return my_list
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
  [(x,y) for x in xrange(0, size) for y in xrange(0, size)]
```

or

```
  ((x,y) for x in xrange(0, size) for y in xrange(0, size))
```

assuming you mean to return an `iterable`, not a `dict`.

Answer (score 0):

you can:

create a new list (`l = []`), and append the coordinates to the list (`l+=[x, y]`)

```
>>> def get_cells(size):
...     l = []
...     for x_axis in range(0, size):
...         x = x_axis
...         for y_axis in range(0, size):
...             y = y_axis
...             l.append([x, y])
...     return l
...
>>> l = get_cells(2)
>>> l
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]]
```

Or use `yield` instead of `return` to be able to iterate over your cells:

```
>>> def get_cells(size):
...     for x_axis in range(0, size):
...         x = x_axis
...         for y_axis in range(0, size):
...             y = y_axis
...             yield (x, y)
...
>>> for i in get_cells(2):
...   print i
...
(0, 0)
(0, 1)
(1, 0)
(1, 1)
```